# Java SQL COUNT Value

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I am trying to return the count value in the attached Java, this is what I have..

```
package com.example.tests;

import java.awt.geom.GeneralPath;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class TestNew {

public void generateid(){

int count;


    try {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://IP:PORT;DatabaseName=blabla;integratedSecurity=true;");
        System.out.println("Connection Successfull");
        System.out.println(conn); 

        //--------------------------------------------------------------------
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        String query1= "SELECT COUNT(*) from dbo.vSubscriberReporting where [SubscriberEmailAddressStatusID] in (5,1,6,7) and [SubscriberStatusID] = 1 AND [SubscriberAddresseeStatusID] = 1 and CompanySizeCodeID IN (4)";
        ResultSet rs= stmt.executeQuery(query1);

count = rs.getInt(1);  
//i cant store the count value from query in this variable... Please help me.
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestNew gen = new TestNew();
    gen.generateid();

}
}
```

the query runs, but comes back with

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The result set has no current row.
```

though I know there should be data, just a single COUNT record..

I would like to be able to store the result to a variable i guess and use it later to verify a field in a selenium script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `rs.next()` before trying to call `getInt(1)`

```
if(rs.next()) //Expecting one row.
{
    count = rs.getInt(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As it s a single result; you can also do this way :

```
rs.moveFirst();
count = rs.getInt(1);
```